# What's wrong with this group by query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

My DB structure: 
[image]

Each "wp_custombill" have many "wp_customuser"

I want to query all the custombill, each custombill have sum of its customuser. My query is

```
select cb.ID, cb.Description, cb.amount, SUM(cu.amount) 
from wp_customuser as cu 
inner join wp_custombill as cb 
    on cu.email = cb.Email
group by cb.ID, cb.Description, cb.amount
```

But the result seem like `sum(cu.Amount)` summary all of CustomUser's records.
[image]

Comment: Sample data and desire output will help to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your `wp_custombill` ids (1,2,3) have same `email`
But without data sample is hard to test.

Otherwise your query looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

In GROUP BY clause we have to write the field, over which we decide the aggregation is done. For your situation your field is customer not the bill. For each customer we have to sum the bill amount. So the query would look like-

```
select cu.payentId, cb.ID, cb.Description, cb.amount, SUM(cu.amount) 
from wp_customuser as cu 
inner join wp_custombill as cb 
    on cu.email = cb.Email
group by cu.payentId
```

In this query we find the all bill associated with single customer by join on user table on email. You can use `cu.email or cb.email` in group by also.

Comment: You cant `group by cu.payentId`, when first field is `cb.ID`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i agree, we can add column. i changed

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to group with all columns. if you group them with description or amount field, then you may get duplicate records.

```
select cb.ID, cb.Description, cb.amount, SUM(cu.amount) 
from wp_customuser as cu 
inner join wp_custombill as cb 
    on cu.email = cb.Email
group by cb.email
```